# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null using javascript in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use native javascript in react to bind event .Actually I am getting some `HTML` from server .I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to set HTML .Now I want to bind a click event in incoming HTML from server here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-shadow-1c4v8?file=/src/App.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const alertFunc = function () {
      alert("-----");
    };
    document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", alertFunc, false);
    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      document
        .querySelector(".btn")
        .removeEventListener("click", alertFunc, false);
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because of your template - `<button className="btn">set countor </button>` is redering like below.

[image]

So that if you try to access using class query selector, it will return undefined. You can use `class` instead of `className`.

```
 return {
    __html: '<button class="btn">set countor </button>'
  };
```

Working Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-meadow-qitjb?file=/src/App.js:87-157

Comment: it is showing error when I am printing value of counter https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wright-vbeqf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: try this - https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-booth-c7l66

Answer (score 1):

It's because your HTML isn't HTML. It's JSX. `className` is a JavaScript-only attribute.

Instead of:

```html
<button className="btn">set countor </button>
```

You need:

```html
<button class="btn">set counter</button>
```

Comment: it is showing error when I am printing value of counter https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wright-vbeqf?file=/src/App.js